# How to add custom attribute to html (form) from models form?

Tags: django

This is standard checkbox from model forms:

In my HTML I have: `{{form}}`

In website source:

```
<div class="id_accept-control-group control-group">
   <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="id_accept" /> <span>Accept</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to add custom attribute: `disabled="disabled" checked="checked"` (to input)?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this question to point you in the right direction [Django: How do I add arbitrary html attributes to input fields on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form)

Also take a look at the model forms django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/