# How do I add data-role="something" to my django form field?

Tags: jquery, django, html, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I want to use bootstrap tagsinput feature in my form. For that I need to add `data-role="tagsinput"`. Is there a way that I can include this thing in my field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `attrs` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) on your widget, for example in a ModelForm:

```
class FooModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        widgets = {
            'yourfield': forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-role': 'tagsinput'})
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use django-crispy-forms (https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms). It has bootstrap support.
You can manage attributes and css classes very easy:

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html

Read "Layout objects attributes"

I highly recommend to use this project