# Django custom form template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I've a custom template to render my form in my Django website. This code renders the ChoiceFields:

```
<select id="{{ "id_"|add:field.html_name }}"
        class="form-control"
        name="{{ field.html_name }}">
    {% for id, name in field.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ id }}"
            {% if field.value|default_if_none:"" == id %}
                selected="selected"
            {% endif %}
            >{{ name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This code works perfectly, when the ChoiceField does not have an initial value. If I sumbit the form, but there's an error in the form (sp I get back to my form, and all the data is in there as I submitted it), the correct choice get the `selected="selected"` attribute, so it works perfectly fine.

But when I set the default value for the form in my Django view (correctly in the form's init() function, like this: `self.fields['card_type'].initial = self.card.card_type_id`), this stops working.

If I put manually somewhere in my template the `form.value` variable it displays the correct integer. In the `id, name for-loop` there's the same `id` value. These do not have any whitespace ot something else there. But the code does not works, does not equals to true the `self.fields['card_type'].initial = self.card.card_type_id` condition.

If I modify the previous code, to print the `id`, and the `field.value` instead of the `{{name}}`, like this: `({{id}}-{{ field.value }})`, the following HTML code'll be generated:

```
<select id="id_card_type" class="form-control" name="card_type">
    <option value="3">(3-2)</option>
    <option value="2">(2-2)</option>
    <option value="1">(1-2)</option>
</select>
```

There's the `id`, which is 1, 2, and 3! There's the `form.value`, which is 2! But there isn't any `selected="selected"`... Why not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this at all, instead of just using `{{ form.my_field_name }}` which would do it all for you?

Comment: I'd like to add the `class` tag for the `<select>`. edit: oh, I see, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form)'s the answer for that. I don't like it, cause it's very hard-coded in my form, not in my template :-(