# Using HTML tags in django form fields

Tags: html, django, forms

When iterating in fields of a (non-model) django form as follows:

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-inline">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<div id="div_{{ field.html_name }}" class="form-group">
<strong>{{ field.label_tag }}</strong> {{ field }}                                   
</div>
{% endfor %} 
</form>
```

The `<strong>` tag is not actually applied to the label.
Is there any way around this (without using Metaclass in the actual form class or using inline styling for the `<span>` element?

Comment: The only reason that the strong stye wouldn't be applied is if there's a specific CSS rule that gives the labels `font-weight: normal`.

Comment: The same happens with e.g. the `<u>` tag. Could this also be overridden by a css rule?

Comment: Sure, anything can. Maybe you are using a reset stylesheet that sets all the default styles to plain?

Answer (score 2):

you may use a css selector like .

```
    .form-group>label{ 
        ...
        font-weight: bold;
        ...
    }
```

other options are ...

1. Use the FormField html ID attribute as a css selector. (it works for specific fields, when you want to apply the *style* for single fields.

   ```
   #form-field-id{ font-weight: bold; }
   ```
2. Use a *html class attribute*. in this case you have two choices to set the widget attribute. Set a parameter in your ModelForm class Field or rewrite the widget template.

Comment: you may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form