# Django template tag slice not working for form slicing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

What's wrong with this code? I am trying to slice this but it's not working. Django version 2.x and Python version 3.5

```
    {% for field in form|slice:":3"  %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{field.label_tag }}
        </td>
        <td>{{field}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Looks like it should be `{{field.label_tag }}`?

Comment: Okay I will change this to 'field' my problem is it's not slicing the form. The whole form is coming to html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `slice` with form directly. But you can use [`form.visible_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) instead:

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields|slice:":3"  %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{field.label_tag }}
    </td>
    <td>{{field}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Can I set hidden field while looping through form.visible_fields? Suppose I want first 3 field hidden and want to show the rest? I want it in template.

Comment: @SamiulSk you are welcome! I not sure it's possiple to add hidden attribute in template. But you can do this in form class for specific fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form

Comment: Actually I am slicing a model form into few steps(pages) so I am slicing a form validating and storing the cleaned value in session  and going to another view(second  step) and initialising the session data to form. That's why I need to change it in template.

Comment: @SamiulSk Try this solution: https://blog.joeymasip.com/how-to-add-attributes-to-form-widgets-in-django-templates/