# How to add attributes to a Django form widget's media fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can render [media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/media/#paths-in-asset-definitions) for a django form, through a custom widget, like this:

```
class TinyMCEWidget(Textarea):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        attrs.update({
            'class':'listing-template',
        })
        super().__init__(attrs)

    class Media:
        js = ('https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/my_api_key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js/',)
```

But I need to add `referrerpolicy="origin"` to the script.  Is there a way this can be done *without* a javascript hack?

> How can I add attributes to a widget's media fields through the widget or form class?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form) question shows how I can add an arbitrary amount of attributes *to a form widget*, but **does not** show how to add attributes to a widget's media fields, therefor my question is not a duplicate.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: @pasevin I don't think it's possible as of Django 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS class which is in [django-js-asset](https://pypi.org/project/django-js-asset/)

```
from js_asset import JS


class TinyMCEWidget(Textarea):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "listing-template",
            }
        )
        super().__init__(attrs)

    class Media:
        js = (
            JS(
                "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/my_api_key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js/",
                {
                    "referrerpolicy": "origin",
                },
                static=False,
            ),
        )
```